# Numbering a spherical grid (of pentagons and hexagons) so neighbours are easily calculated?

Tags: geometry

I'm making a grid-based game with a spherical world. Currently I'm using a grid of 12 pentagons and variable number of hexagons to create grids of different sizes. So they look like this:

[image]

Currently to find which tile boarders which it's basically hard-coded. I just have a file with all of this information for each size of grid I support.

I was however wondering, would it be possible to give each tile a number in such a way that it's relatively simple to calculate the neighboring tile's number from it? On a planar rectangular grid this is simple: neighbours(a,b) = [(a-1,b), (a+1,b), (a,b-1), (a,b+1)]. But is there some smart numbering scheme for this kind of grid that allows?

I'm not expecting the calculating to be as easy as those for the rectagle grid, but anything that's not just hard-coded data would be interesting. Depending on how simple it is I will be using the data of this numbering scheme, but either way it's something interesting to know I think.

Comment: How can you tile a sphere this way. Where three hexagons meet, the total angle is 360 degrees, so the three are coplanar ??

Comment: @bubba: The hexagons are on a curved surface; Euclidean geometry does not apply.

Comment: You could first separate the tiles into groups: the pentagons one group, the hexagons surrounding a pentagon another, the hexagons between two pentagons another, the hexagons at the perimeter of a hexagon group, and the hexagons inside the hexagon groups. The connectivity between groups is simple. However, I'm not sure how to *orient* each hexagon/pentagon properly. (That is, of course we can number their sides, and thus decide on an orientation, but how to combine group membership and orientation, is not immediately clear to me.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal -- how did you conclude that the hexagons are non-planar? The OP is creating a game, so he's doing computer graphics. This means he's probably using planar polygons, since that's all that graphics cards understand, at the lowest levels. The word "hexagon" means a planar thing with straight sides, to most people. So, at the very least, some clarification is needed.

Comment: @bubba: The polygons on the sphere do not exactly match the polygons used on a planar surface. The sphere illustrates their connectivity; i.e. which polygons share sides. The distortion between the two (planar and on the sphere) is minimal, and can be ignored for the purposes of this question. Indeed, even the actual exact shapes of the tiles are irrelevant for this question; only the number of sides on each matters. The OP just wants to know how to compute a label each tile, and how to use the labels to compute their connectivity graph or matrix (i.e., neighbours).

Comment: @NominalAnimal is right. Of course the hexagons aren't technically curved, they are made up of meshes to represent them. However, I didn't think this would made any difference for the question. All I need for the final rendering is the center of each tile. And as NominalA said, all I'm looking for is a way to number/name/label each tile, and calculate their neighbours from that. However currently it just seems easiest to have this information as a simple matrix (I already use this now, but perhaps there was a better way).

Comment: The Oddler, you need the center and the orientation, I believe, so you can label the edges correctly. I think a matrix or a graph *is* the most useful form, but I also think it is possible to (pre-)compute the matrix or graph, for each valid size of a triangular set of hexagons. How have you generated the matrixes you already have?

Comment: @bubba: I hope I am not annoying you with this; I'm only trying to help, so please do take this as a honest attempt at that. Consider a cube. Three squares meet at each corner. The sum of their angles is $90°+90°+90°=270°$. If you have three hexagons butted together, they are planar, with the sum of their angles $120°+120°+120°=360°$. On the sphere, three hexagons meeting are not planar, but curved; their internal angles must therefore be less than $120°$. Yet, [...]

Comment: [...] if we measure *along the surface of the sphere*, the internal angles *are* 120°. Because the regions where there are only hexagonal polygons are not flat, they are not "real" (planar) hexagons; either the tiles are not all the same shape, their edges and vertices are not symmetric, or their six vertices are not coplanar. The last is the most typical case. In all three cases, the difference to a planar hexagon is so small, it does not matter.

Comment: @bubba: However, if your complaint is that the shapes on the sphere cannot be pentagons and hexagons, you are correct: they are so *only in the planar representation*. The ones on the sphere are close analogs, but not exactly the same shapes. Yet, the differences are imperceptible, and because the tiles' shapes on the sphere do not actually matter, OP is calling them too pentagons and hexagons. Perhaps it would be better to call them, say, *pentagonal and hexagonal tiles on the sphere*. But I honestly do not know; I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: @NominalAnimal True, I indeed also need the orientation. Though if I know the position and the center, that's easy to calculate afterwards. Currently what I did to create the matrix is generate an icosphere, use its vertexes as centers for the tiles, and edges as lines to the neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but explores the features of the mapping/connectivity of the .. tiles.

I do believe that the smallest such sphere is described by the [truncated rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Truncated_rhombic_triacontahedron.png) with one hexagon between each pair of pentagons); the next one is the [Conway polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Conway_polyhedron_Dk6k5tI.png) with two hexagons between each pair of pentagons, and so on.

The 12 pentagons are located at the vertices of a regular icosahedron. (Or, equivalently, at the centers of each face of a regular dodecahedron, those two being duals.)

This means there are 20 "faces" with a group of hexagons in each, and 30 edges (rows of hexagons between two pentagons).

If we use $N$ for the number of hexagons between each pair of pentagons, $N = 0$ would correspond to a dodecahedron, $N = 1$ to a truncated rhombic triacontahedron, $N = 2$ to a Conway polyhedron, and so on. Let us exclude the $N = 0$ case, because there would be no hexagons at all in that case, so it'd be a special case anyway.

If we exclude the hexagons directly between two pentagons from each hexagon group, we have a triangular group of hexagons with $N-1$ on each side; thus, each such group is composed of
$$\frac{N (N - 1)}{2}$$
hexagons; see e.g. [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) at wikipedia for explanation.

So, we end up with

- $N_p = 12$ pentagons (each at the vertex of an icosahedron)
- $N_b = 30 N$ hexagons, total (between each pair of pentagons, only considering pentagons connected by a corresponding edge in an icosahedron, of course)
- $N_h = 20 N (N+1) / 2 = 10 N (N-1)$ hexagons, total (in the triangular groups of hexagons, corresponding roughly to the faces of a dodecahedron)

and therefore 12 pentagons and $10 N (N-1) + 30 N = 10 N (N+2) = 10 N^2 + 20 N$ hexagons, total, for $0 \le N \in \mathbb{Z}$.

To generate a connectivity graph or matrix -- myself preferring a graph, because that makes it easier to specify which edge of a tile is connected to which edge of another tile --, I'd first construct the 30 strings of hexagonal tiles, each a straight line, and connect their ends to the pentagons. Note that there are logically two different types of such lines of tiles: with an odd number of tiles, and an even number of tiles. The ones with an even number of tiles are easier to construct and connect, so you might wish to restrict $N$ to an even number.

Next, I'd create the 20 sets of hexagons arranged in a triangle with $N-1$ hexagons per side, and their interconnections. I think row by row should work fine, starting with a longest row. Stitching them into three tile strings already connected to the pentagons depends on the orientation of the group, so you might wish to write different functions for different groups, to make stitching them in to the graph or matrix easier.

All in all, I don't see any particular point of difficulty, except for the extreme care to detail and checking needed to make sure it works correctly. For example, if you number the edges counterclockwise from $0$ to $4$ for the pentagons, and from $0$ to $5$ for the hexagons, then a connectivity graph will have exactly one undirected edge from one edge to one other edge; this also explicitly defines the orientation of each pentagon/hexagon in relation to its neighbours. I would personally use some software to use 3D, maybe balls to represent the nodes and sticks for edges in the graph, so that verifying each step of stitching would be easier.

A similar technique can be used in 3D, constructing non-Euclidean geometries with each room/tile having local Euclidean geometry; like in the movie Cube. You just have compatible openings between tiles, and decide which tiles share an opening (an edge in 2D, a face in 3D). (In 3D -- and in 2D too, if you count reflecting/mirroring --, you also need to specify the rotation and/or reflection around the axis between the two.)

Hmm. Are there any board games using tiles that can be flipped, that represent two different worlds? Maybe with the board vertical between the players, so each player only sees their own side? Might lead to interesting gameplay mechanics, if the tile face pairings and the rules for flipping a tile work...